# Getting go to work as http client

Tags: http, go, httpclient

I am trying to get response from a json api, but I am getting `<nil>` as a body. I dont know what is wrong. Here is code snippet

```
client := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://example.com", 
  bytes.NewBufferString("{\"a\": \"b\"}"))
resp, err := client.Do(req)
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
var f interface{}
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &f)
fmt.Println(f);
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Please, get in the habit to check `err` for non-nilness, like `if err != nil { panic(err) }`. It will save you lot of time.

Comment: @kavu it is there, just omitted from this one. Remember it is just code snippet

Comment: please show how you check your errors. If you're getting a nil response, you're missing an error check somewhere.

Comment: You should also check resp.StatusCode. If your POST successfully retrieves a 404 message, err will be nil.

Comment: @andybalholm thank you for pointing that. It was indeed 4xx error. Fixed that

Comment: @ducktyped Hi, I noticed this question is still in the Unanswered queue. Could you please provide an answer and approve it... :)